# Comparing two objects to get matching elements

Tags: javascript

I am comparing two different objects with identical structures:

Object 1:

```
[{
    "date": "2019-10-07",
    "price": "1313.01"
}, {
    "date": "2019-10-08",
    "price": "1276.21"
}, {
    "date": "2019-10-09",
    "price": "1257.75"
}]
```

Object 2:

```
[{
    "date": "2019-10-07",
    "price": "2000.10"
}, {
    "date": "2019-10-09",
    "price": "1356.75"
}]
```

I am trying to return an array of prices based on the dates. In my example, I am trying to return

```
["2000.10", "1276.21", "1356.75"]
```

This array will return all of the prices of Object 2. However, you can see that that Object 2 does not include the date of "2019-10-08", so I need to return the price of that date from Object 1. These object lengths are dynamic, but Object 1 will always be longer than Object 2, since I am getting missing values from Object 1.

The array that is returned will always be the size of Object 1. The problem I am facing is looping through and checking prices based on indexes.

My attempt was to loop through Object 1, then check to see if the dates matched for each index. However, I ran into issues when the dates didn't match, so the index was out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Map` and `map`

- Create a `Map` from second array using `date` as key
- Loop through first array, if date is available on `Mapper` use value from `Mapper` for corresponding `date`, else use the price of current element

```js
let a = [{"date": "2019-10-07","price": "1313.01"},{"date":"2019-10-08","price": "1276.21"},{"date": "2019-10-09","price": "1257.75"}]
let b = [{ "date": "2019-10-07","price": "2000.10"},{"date": "2019-10-09","price": "1356.75"}]

let mapper = new Map(b.map(({ date, price }) => [date, price]))

let final = a.map(({ date, price }) => {
  return mapper.has(date) ? mapper.get(date) : price
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: guess I was too slow to answer :D

Comment: @DhananjaiPai may be this time not always :) have a good day mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert those to objects, then merge those and took values:

```js
const toObject = array => Object.fromEntries(
  array.map(
    ({date,price}) => [date, price]
  )
);

const prices = Object.values(
  Object.assign(
    toObject(array1),
    toObject(array2)
  )
);
```

You can combine as many arrays as you want with this approach:

```js
const prices = Object.values(
  Object.assign(
    ...arrays.map(toObject)
  )
);
```

It will always take the last item with the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` and `find`, if find result from `arr2` is `undefined` will use the value from `arr1`.

```
const arr1 = [{
    "date": "2019-10-07",
    "price": "1313.01"
}, {
    "date": "2019-10-08",
    "price": "1276.21"
}, {
    "date": "2019-10-09",
    "price": "1257.75"
}];

const arr2 = [{
    "date": "2019-10-07",
    "price": "2000.10"
}, {
    "date": "2019-10-09",
    "price": "1356.75"
}];

const result = arr1.map((item) => (arr2.find((item2) => item.date === item2.date) || item).price);
```